# Перехват исключение из неуправляемого кода .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Есть сторонняя библиотека на плюсах которая забирает лог с устройства(сканера отпечатка пальцев) и отдает управляемому коду. Библиотека переодически спрашивает у устройства какие пользователи на него загружены и каких нет грузит туда пользователя с отпечатками. Период в 1 час. Параметры передаются правильные.

Проблема в возникновении ошибки в непредсказуемый момент времени когда крашится C++ библиотека. Конкретнее когда пытается забрать список загруженных на устройство пользователей, даже когда список пользователей и отпечатков не менялся.

Пробовал добавлять аттрибуты HandleCorruptState и ловить AccessViolation, Win32Exception, ExternalException, Exception, по отдельности и все вместе взятое и ничего, процесс просто падает.

Версия .NET 4.6.1.

P.S. Ловил AccessViolation в первую очередь, так как при неправильных параметрах передаваемых в плюсовую либу она кидала именно это исключение. Вывод в лог при UnhandledException тоже есть и в логах пусто.

ВОПРОС: Как решить эту проблему? Либо поймать исключение, либо как-то изолировать рабочую область чтобы ее можно было бы перезагрузить.

Код: https://pastebin.com/MZB9VwY9

Comment: Написать собственную обёртку на C++ для этой библиотеки, и использовать ее в C# коде. Доступные к экспорту функции должны быть объявлены как `extern C`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такой вылет может происходить при повреждении управляемой кучи. Куча может повредиться если вы передаете библиотеке управляемый массив, а она что-то записывает за его границами. Или запоминает адрес и обращается к нему когда там уже ничего не лежит. Если вы подозреваете подобную ситуацию - попробуйте добавить методу, который ловит исключения, атрибут [`[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) - это поможет отловить такую ситуацию. Но это лишь средство диагностики, программа с поврежденной кучей неработоспособна.

Если дело и правда в повреждении кучи, то сделать можно вот что.

Во-первых, надо проверить (прочитав в документации) как долго библиотека собирается держать у себя переданные ей массивы. Если дольше чем один вызов метода - то надо выделять ей копию массива при помощи [`Marshal.AllocHGlobal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_AllocHGlobal_System_IntPtr_). То же самое касается любых передаваемых по ссылке структур.

Во-вторых, если есть подозрение что все вызовы правильные, а проблема - в выходе за границу, то нужно выделять память через [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx), оставив с обоих сторон по зарезервированной странице. Это поможет превратить выход за границы массива в немедленный AccessViolationException, который можно обработать.

---

Но краш C++ библиотеки не обязательно сопровождается исключением. Вот еще возможные способы:

[std::quick_exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/quick_exit), [std::exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit), [std::abort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort), [std::terminate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate)

И все - только стандартные способы, а ведь есть еще и WINAPI...

Если библиотека использует что-либо из выше перечисленного - ее надо изолировать в отдельный дочерний процесс, и перезапускать его при падениях. Заодно избавитесь от возможных утечек памяти на стороне библиотеки. Общаться с дочерним процессом можно через Remoting, WCF или по велосипедному бинарному протоколу.

Comment: Сам думал об изоляции в отдельный процесс, но также думал может есть более изящное решение. Благодарю